# Trying to pass list value from python to html

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to pass list values (from 'ci' list below) into my wepage using python. The list values contain URLs for images which will go in the HTML <img src {{ listname[1] }} tag (see HTML below for more info). However, when I try the below code and render the template on my local server the img does not appear and when I inspect element the img src tag is empty.

My code is below:

**Python**

```
@app.route('/route', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def _get_gallery():
    df=pd.read_csv('C:\\username\\foldername\\excelfile.csv')
    images=list(df["image"].values)
    clean_images=[]
    for image in images:
        if "https" in str(image):
            clean_images.append(image)

    ci=pd.DataFrame(clean_images)
    return render_template('template.html', ci=ci)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**The HTML template has the following code to try and pull through the list values:**

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <a href="{{ ci[1] }}">
            <img class="img" src="{{ ci[1] }}" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to convert the list to pandas DataFrame, try to comment this line and see if its work

Comment: Where is this file found and what is called? It is your `views.py`?

Comment: @Elkana Bardugo This solved the problem. You made it look so easy, Thank you very much!